Conditional Likelihood exponential distribution
Let $X_1, ... X_n$ be iid Exp($\lambda$), where $\lambda > 0$.
How does the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) of $\lambda$ change if we somehow are told that all $X_i$ overshot their mean?
(i.e.: let's condition on the event $\{X_i > E[X_i] | i = 1, ..., n\}$)

What is the context? How do you know for sure about overshooting? You must somehow modify the model ...

Re "told:" how does your interlocutor know or surmise this is the case?  That is, what is the specific information you are relying on?

The notation is ambiguous, as it is not clear whether $\lambda$ is the rate or the scale of the Exponential. I will assume that it is the rate, so $\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\lambda^{-1}$.
From the memoryless property of the Exponential, conditioning on $X_i>\lambda^{-1}$ just shifts the density to the right by $\lambda^{-1}$, so this becomes
$$
f_{X}(x|X>\lambda^{-1})=\lambda e^{-\lambda (x-\lambda^{-1})}=\lambda e^{-\lambda x + 1} ,\, \text{ for } \, x > \lambda^{-1}
$$
The likelihood is then
$$
L(\lambda)=\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda e^{-\lambda x_i +1} \mathbf{1}_{(\lambda^{-1},\infty)}(x_i) \propto \lambda^n e^{-\lambda n \bar{x}} \mathbf{1}_{(\lambda^{-1},\infty)}(\min_i x_i)
$$
Can you see where this is maximised? Hint: there are two possibilities.
